# Redirigir la salida de un comando al principio de un archivo en bash

Tags: linux, bash, servidor, pipe

Estoy haciendo un configurador de red en *Bash*, y necesito agregar varias líneas al fichero `/etc/resolv.conf`. Haciendo `echo "hola" » fichero.txt` se agrega al final, pero, ¿Cómo consigo que se agregue al inicio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay distintas maneras de hacerlo. Antes de nada, pero, es importante recordar que el fichero `/etc/resolv.conf` es sensible y modificarlo erróneamente puede tener consecuencias malas. Por tanto, **siempre realiza una copia de seguridad antes de modificarlo**.

Tal y como vemos en [How to insert a text at the beginning of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9533679/1983854) podemos utilizar estos métodos:

```
echo "hola" | cat - fichero > nuevo_fichero

sed '1s/^/hola\n/' fichero > nuevo_fichero

{ printf "hola\n"; cat fichero; } > nuevo_fichero
```

Todos ellos crean un fichero nuevo. Si quieres editar el fichero en sí, utiliza `sed -i.bak '...' fichero`. Esto modificará `fichero` y creará una copia de seguridad llamada `fichero.bak`.

Pruebas:

```
$ cat fichero
1
2
3
$ echo "hola" | cat - fichero
hola
1
2
3
$ sed '1s/^/hola\n/' fichero
hola
1
2
3
```

Editando el mismo fichero con `i`:

```
$ sed -i.bak '1s/^/hola\n/' fichero
$ cat fichero
hola                   # ¡el original se modificó!
1
2
3
$ cat fichero.bak
1                      # ¡es una copia de seguridad!
2
3
```

Comment: No me termina de funcionar: Mi código es ``` sed -i.back '1s/^/ $ip   $HOSTNAME.$dominio  $HOSTNAME\n/' /etc/resolv.conf``` y me muestra sólo la ip y un punto

Comment: @ras212 esto es porque utilizas comillas simples. Tienes que usarlas dobles para que la variable se expanda: `sed -i.back "1s/^/ $ip $HOSTNAME.$dominio $HOSTNAME\n/" /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: He utilizado las comillas, pero no lee $HOSTNAME

Comment: @ras212 entonces deberías editar tu pregunta e indicar **exactamente** qué estás utilizando. Esto quiere decir indicar qué variables tienes definidas, qué contiene el fichero y qué comando ejecutas. Si no, estaremos dando palos de ciego.

Comment: Mi script completo: https://pastebin.com/261GWPNc La línea con sed: sed -i.back "1s/^/ $ip   $HOSTNAME.$search  $HOSTNAME\n/" /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: @ras212 `$HOSTNAME` no está definido.

Comment: Pero si pones echo $HOSTNAME en terminal te sale el nombre de tu máquina..

Comment: @ras212 veo que se solucionó tu problema. ¿Cuál fue la solución?

Comment: para obtener el hostname hostname=$(hostname -f)